# Nested Dict As HttpRequest Django

Tags: python, django, dictionary, elasticsearch, url-encoding

I am trying to write some test cases for some code I've developed using Elasticsearch and Django. The concept is straightforward - I just want to test a get request, which will be an Elasticsearch query. However, I am constructing the query as a nested dict. When I pass the nested dict to the Client object in the test script it gets passed through Django until it ends up at the urlencode function which doesn't look like it can handle nested dicts only MultivalueDicts. Any suggestions or solutions? I don't want to use any additional packages as I don't want to depend on potentially non-supported packages for this application.

Generic Code:

```
class MyViewTest(TestCase):
    es_connection = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch("localhost:9200")

    def test_es_query(self):
        client = Client()
        query = {
            "query": {
                "term": {
                    "city": "some city"
                }
            }
        }
        response = client.get("", query)
        print(response)
```

Link for urlencode function: [urlencode Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/utils/http/#urlencode)

The issue is clearly at the conditional statement when the urlencode function checks if the dictionary value is a str or bytes object. If it isn't it creates a generator object which can never access the nested portions of the dictionary.

**EDIT: 07/25/2018**

So I was able to come up with a temporary work around to at least run the test. However, it is ugly and I feel like there must be a better way. The first thing I tried was specifying the content_type and converting the dict to a json string first. However, Django still kicked back and error in the urlencode function.

```
    class MyViewTest(TestCase):
    es_connection = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch("localhost:9200")

    def test_es_query(self):
        client = Client()
        query = {
            "query": {
                "term": {
                    "city": "some city"
                }
            }
        }
        response = client.get("", data=json.dumps(query), content_type="application/json")
        print(response)
```

So instead I had to do:

```
    class MyViewTest(TestCase):
    es_connection = elasticsearch.Elasticsearch("localhost:9200")

    def test_es_query(self):
        client = Client()
        query = {
            "query": {
                "term": {
                    "city": "some city"
                }
            }
        }
        query = json.dumps(query)
        response = client.get("", data={"q": query}, content_type="application/json")
        print(response)
```

This let me send the HttpRequest to my View and parse it back out using:

```
json.loads(request.GET["q"])
```

Then I was able to successfully get the requested data from Elasticsearch and return it as an HttpResponse. I feel like in Django though there has to be a way to just pass a json formatted string directly to the Client object's get function. I thought specifying the content_type as application/json would work but it still calls the urlencode function. Any ideas? I really don't want to implement this current system into production.

Comment: You presumably want a POST request rather than a GET here, and the contents should be JSON.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Actually I want a GET request here as I am trying to retrieve data from Elasticsearch itself. I've tried using a straight json string while specifying the content_type however, this didn't work either (see my edit).